# Average decreasing non-sequential sub-list length in a random list

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, integers

Let $l$ be a randomised list of integers $\in[1,r]$ of length $n$.

We will construct a sequence as such :

- Take the first value of $l$
- For each subsequent value, add it to the sequence if it is equal or lesser than the previous one we added, until the end of $l$

What is the average length of that sequence, as a function of $r$ and $n$ ?

---

To answer this, we could also ask : What is the probability $p$ that $l$ contains such a sequence of length at least $m$ ?

The obvious cases are of course $m=1\Rightarrow p = 1$ and $m > n \Rightarrow p = 0$, however I haven't been able to formulate a function of $m$, $n$ and $r$.

---

Here are examples of valid sequences :

- From $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$ we get $(1)$
- From $[3, 2, 4, 1]$ we get $(3, 2, 1)$
- From $[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]$ we get $(2, 1, 1, 1)$
- From $[4, 1, 3, 2]$ we only get $(4, 1)$ as the sequence *must* be greedy.

---

I encountered this interesting problem while trying to explain why the `strand_sort` algorithm is faster than `bubble_sort` despite being of the same time complexity class. I want to use the answer to this problem to calculate the average number of values `strand_sort` removes from the list it is sorting each time it iterates, however I think it is beyond my ability to solve myself.

Comment: For ```strand_sort```, we also require that sequence is built greedy - for example, list [4,1,3,2] gives sequence (4, 1) and not (4, 3, 2). Are you interested in longest sequence, or in sequence used in ```strand_sort```?

Comment: @mihaild That is a good remark, I will add this to the post !